# How to reverse titleLabel's shadowoffset of a UIButton for it's highlighted state?

Tags: uibutton, shadow

I wanted to make a `UIButton` with a shadow effect `[UIButtonInst titleLabel].shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1)` (//shadow below text) for normal state while `CGSizeMake(0, -1)` (//shadow over the text) for highlighted state.

I read the documentation for `UIButton`. It seems that the `[UIButtonInst titleLabel].shadowOffset` cannot be set for different states. There are `setBackgroundImage:forState`, and `setTitleColor:forState`, but there is no such `setTitleShadowOffset:forState`.

Is there a way to make that happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it in documents,

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL reversesTitleShadowWhenHighlighted
```

is exactly what I need.

Need to read documents more carefully, :p

Answer (score -1):

You can also use:

```
button.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);
```

If you want the inverse effect without highlight.